# How to calculate the array length in a JSON object array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a **JSON (Line A)** as shown below in which I want to calculate the number of items in a JSON object array.

```
   $fp = fopen('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
    fclose($fp);
    logActivity();

    if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json'));
    }

    {"toggle_multi_tiles":["0","1"]}  // Line A
```

At this moment, it is 2. It can be three as well or sometimes 4.

This is what I have tried:

```
$data->toggle_multi_tiles.length;   // Line B
```

On doing `echo $data->toggle_multi_tiles.length;` it returns `Arraylength` which is not the right output I am getting.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above at Line B so that it returns  2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count` to count the number of elements in PHP Array

```
count ( $data->toggle_multi_tiles ) ;
```